# Let a, b, d be non-zero integers. If d|a and d|b, prove d|gcd(a,b)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

So I think I have a solution to this problem but I'm not certain if it works or not.

> **Problem Statement:**

Let a, b, d be non-zero integers. If d|a and d|b, show that d|gcd(a,b).

> **Attempted Proof**

Let $\gcd(a,b) = k$ for some $k$ in integers.

By Bezout's Identity, we can write this as $ax + by = k$ for some $x, y$ in integers.

We know $d|a$ and $d|b$; this implies that $d|ax$ and $d|by$

Since this means d divides all terms on the left side, it divides the entire left side:$ d|ax + by$

This implies $d|k$ which implies $d|\gcd(a,b)$.

Could someone please verify if my solution is valid or not?

Comment: It's valid if Bezout's lemma can be accepted to be true.  Good job.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. See the linked dupe for more.